# Pytest test file that reads from current directory

Tags: unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to do a unit test with Pytest on a function of the form

```py
def function():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        # read for information in file
    return information_from_file
```

I want to make a temporary directory which I can use the function to read from. This lead me to using `tmpdir` and `tmpdir_factory`, however both these options require that a path object is inputted as an argument from what I can tell. Though in this case, that isn't an option since the function is reading from the current directory rather than a directory that was inputted.

Is there a way to use Pytest in order to do a test on this kind of function?

Comment: You could use [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) to provide the wanted file content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open), but that would be a [glass-box test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) breaking the encapsulation of the function. If the filename changes, the test breaks. If it changes its implementation, the test breaks.

More importantly, *it ignores what your test is telling you*.

Testing is a great way to find out where your design is too rigid. If you find a function hard to test, its probably hard to use. Hard coded filenames are a classic example. This is an opportunity to make the code more flexible. For example, introduce a configuration object.

```
def function():
    with open(MyApp.config('function','file'), 'r') as file:
        # read for information in file
    return information_from_file
```

Exactly how this is implemented depends on your situation. You can use Python's built in [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to work with the config file. And here I've gone with an application [singleton object](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm) to store application-wide information.

Then you have two tests. One which checks the default `MyApp.config('function','file')` is as expected. And other which sets `MyApp.config('function','file')` to a temp file and tests the function reads it.